# How manipulate .csv file contents, using PHP, into an HTML table?

Tags: php, csv

OK, here's what I've got so far:

```
<table class="tftable" border="1">
    <tr><th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th><th>Header 3</th><th>Header 4</th><th>Header 5</th><th>Header 6</th><th>Header 7</th></tr>
    <?php
        define('CSV_PATH','/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/SITEPREVIEW/csv_file_drop_folder/');
        $csv_file = CSV_PATH . "test.csv";
        if(($handle=fopen($csv_file,"r"))!== FALSE){
            fgetcsv($handle);
            while(($data=fgetcsv($handle,1000,","))!==FALSE){
                $num = count($data);
                for($c=0;$c<$num;$c++){
                    $col[$c]=$data[$c];
                }
                $col1=$col[0];
                $col2=$col[1];
                $col3=$col[2];
                $col4=$col[3];
                $col5=$col[4];
                $col6=$col[5];
                $col7=$col[6];

                echo "<tr><th>".$col1."</th><th>".$col2."</th><th>".$col3."</th><th>".$col4."</th><th>".$col5."</th><th>".$col6."</th><th>".$col7."</th></tr>";
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

So I run this and `($data=fgetcsv($handle,1000,","))` is coming out `FALSE` I think, but not sure why, and so only the headers get printed to the page.

---

Got rid of `fgetcsv($handle);`, but only prints one line, and I checked the file contents of my `.csv` file and this is what I have:

[CSV FILE CONTENTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI2PP.png)

Comment: Does the csv file exist? Does php have rights to view it? What does a row look like? I'd suggest adding some debug statements such as printing `file opened` after `fopen` to be sure it's openable.

Comment: Yes, `test.csv` is in the folder `csv_file_drop_folder`. I put `echo "pig";` above `fgetcsv($handle);` and it printed `pig` on my page.

Comment: I ran `chmod -R 777` on the folder `csv_file_drop_folder`.

Comment: You have a messed up curly quote/apostrophe here: csv_file_drop_folder/’.  That might be it.  Try replacing with a single quote.

Comment: That's just an artifact from pasting into textEdit to make changes to the actual location of the file; that is, I accidentally deleted the ' in textEdit, and then retyped it and got a curly quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of this line:

```
fgetcsv($handle);
```

That is:

```
if(($handle=fopen($csv_file,"r"))!== FALSE){
     while ( ( $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",") ) !== FALSE ) {
```

If this only prints one line, check the line endings on the csv. Make sure they are /n or /r/n

> Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading
>   files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the
>   auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help
>   resolve the problem. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

From which I'd assume the csv may have been generated in a mac. I am not positive, but I believe what was happening was that your first fgetcsv read the first (and only) line of your csv, so the second one, in the while loop, correctly noted there was no further line to read, so returned FALSE, thus terminating the loop before you started.

If the csv is automatically generated, you'd want to correct this issue on that end of things, if it's created on say, a Mac, ideally the tool that created it is corrected to use unix style \n line endings. If that can't be readily done, just open the csv in a code editor, configured to save/convert line ending to unix style, and save it prior to loading.

> LF:    Multics, Unix and Unix-like systems (Linux, OS X, FreeBSD, AIX,
>   Xenix, etc.), BeOS, Amiga, RISC OS, and others[1]
>
> CR:    Commodore 8-bit machines, Acorn BBC, ZX Spectrum, TRS-80, Apple II family, Mac OS up to version 9, and OS-9

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

I was curious, it looks like Macs up to OS 9 used \r, but OS X uses \n as you'd expect. Note that windows uses \r\n which works fine since \r is ignored I believe and \n is present.

Comment: OK, did that just now, however, it only prints out one row.

Comment: You can't take a picture of a line ending, lol. Are you using a mac?

Comment: Perfect, got it! Thank you.

Comment: It was an interesting question, I do these csv reads a lot so the puzzle was why it would fail.

Comment: Now, if I migrate to a non-Mac system can I leave it?

Comment: Most real code editors have an option to set line ending type, unix is the desired one. I can't comment on any other tool. But your csvs should be saved with unix style line endings that way you'll never see this issue again. I had a client who had a similar issue with csv generation in windows, all I had to do to fix their issue was literally open and save their csv in a code editor.